# JQuery UI.Layout.ui-layout-west horizontal text size NOT with Scrollbar but resize panel

Tags: jquery, html, css

layout-latest.js ui-layout-west panel

```
west: {
            paneSelector:           ".ui-layout-west"
        ,   size:                   "auto"
        ,   resizerCursor:          "w-resize"
        ,   customHotkey:           ""
        }
```

The size of the panel adjusts for my listbox if the content gets longer
[image]

More down in the panel I have a file tree

[image]

The text there is cutted with a scrollbar because I gave the whole file tree the css layout

`overflow: auto;`

I want that the panel gets resized to fix the length of the text in the file tree.
[image]

Can somebody help me :)

Answer (score 0):

In layout-latest.js, there is one more west:{} section defined in `$.layout = {}`

Inside this west section you need to write

```
 west: {
       side:left
  ,    cssReq:{    
          overflow:"auto"
          ,height:"auto"  
       }
  }
```

Comment: sorry this is not the answer for ur question

Comment: you can fix the size of the west panel

Comment: the above answer is to add vertical scroll bar when minimize the browser.